# How to create a 3D collage of photos

Tags: images, 3d, perspective

[image: dna strand photo collage]I'm trying to create a line of photos that rotate around the y - axis as you go down so that they resemble a helix DNA shape.

But I haven't had much luck so far.  When I create more than 3 3D extruded objects, it runs out RAM.  And I've tried warping the perspective as you go down the line of photos but that doesn't seem to work when you want warp the perspective of the photo itself, not the contents of the photo.

Can this idea actually be executed?

Hopefully my very crude drawing shows how it should like looking upon a row of buildings with a changing perspective as the strand goes down.  I don't wan't any warping or curving of the photos just a change in perspective.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to give us a at least a sketch of what you want your final results to look like and what program you are using? Please keep in mind that we can only help you with specific issues and not give you a long tutorial for a complicated task.

Comment: Also what application are you using?

Comment: "it runs out of RAM" define "it" please. Probably its not a dedicated 3D program or else you wouldnt have that problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's Photoshop CC 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

But...
You'll need to master After Effects 3D mode to have any hope of doing it in that. AE isn't good at conflating animations in 3D, and is tiresome to use for such things. This makes it more difficult than doing it in a 3D app like 3ds Max, C4D or Maya. But cheaper.